# how not to repeat the same record after spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string, spaces

This code repeats the output after triple spaces. I just want triple spaces after a word, but the output keeps repeating. For example, I just want to see Output: .- (triple spaces) .-;

```
String english = input.nextLine();
char[] toChar = english.toCharArray();
String output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < toChar.length; i++) {
    if (toChar[i] == 'a' || toChar[i] == 'A') {
        output += ".-";
    }
    if (toChar[i] == 'b' || toChar[i] == 'B') {
        output += "-...";
    }
    if (toChar[i] == ' ') {
        output += "   ";
    }
    System.out.print(output + " ");
}
```

**Input**

```
a a
```

**Output**

```
.- .-    .-   .-
```

Comment: Err, but what is the point of your code: what do you intend to do here?

Comment: Move the statement `System.out.print(output + " ");` out of the loop.

Comment: @GhostCat Please correct my code. I just want triple spaces after a word but the output keeps repeating. I just wanna see Output: .- (triple spaces) .-;

Comment: @GhostCat Translating text into Morse Code. But yeah, he could have mentioned it.

Comment: Unrelated: your current approach of having a lengthy if thisChar then thatMorse ... is really not a good idea. You will need one if per character. Consider to use a Map instead (key: character to convert, value: the morse code for that char).

Answer (score 7):

Your post is so confused. Try to be more clear for the future posts. However, your output is repeated because it is inside the loop (repeated for every char of the input data). So, put your `System.out(....);` outside loop.

```
String english = input.nextLine();
char[] toChar = english.toCharArray();
String output = "";

for (int i = 0; i < toChar.length; i++) {
    if (toChar[i] == 'a' || toChar[i] == 'A') {
        output += ".-";
    }
    if (toChar[i] == 'b' || toChar[i] == 'B') {
        output += "-...";
    }
    if (toChar[i] == ' ') {
        output += "   ";
    }
}
System.out.print(output + " ");
```

Comment: How can I add spaces now if i converted from morse to english. Ex. Let e = '.' Input: . (three spaces) . Output: e e.  Here's my code` ` `if(morseDiv[i].equals("( )+")){
    outmorse += " ";
   }
   if(morseDiv[i].equals(".")){
    outmorse += "e";
   } ` ` `